# Hover эффект на блок выше

Tags: css

```html
<div class="test1"></div>
<div class="test3"></div>
<div class="test3"></div>
```

Как тестом 3 на тест 1 повлиять? при ховере ? не + не ~ не помогает

Comment: А с чего вы взяли что в css можете влиять на блоки которые не связанны друг с другом (child) ? то что вы хотите сделать через CSS не выйдет, можете сделать через JS/JQuery

Comment: Тут JS, лучший вариант.

Answer (score 1):

ну в зависимости от структуры, можно попробовать через flex + order

```css
.test {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
}
.test1 {
  order: -2;
}
.test3,
.test1 {
  width: 100%;
  background: gray;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.test3:hover ~ .test1 {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="test3">test3</div>
  <div class="test3">test3</div>
  <div class="test1">test1</div>
</div>
```

Иначе, только через js

Comment: Не получается ( 
http://viniry.kz/ в шапке там стрелка вниз и вот блок снизу при наведении должен блок сверху закрывать но увы при наведении на vc_row:hover ~.phones1{display:none;} не работает на блок выше эта вещьҰ

Comment: не понятно, что вы пишите. Ставьте знаки препинания.

Answer (score 0):

Единственный адекватный способ это ***JS***, или использование библиотеки ***jQuery***.

```js
function getClass(c) {
 return document.getElementsByClassName(c)[0];
}

let jsFirst = getClass("js-first"),
    jsThirst = getClass("js-thirst"),
    jqueryFirst = getClass("jQuery-first"),
    jqueryThirst = getClass("jQuery-thirst");

function hover(elem, aim) {
  
  elem.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    aim.classList.add("hover");
  });
  
  elem.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
    aim.classList.remove("hover");
  });
}

$('.jQuery-first').hover(function(e) {
  $('.jQuery-thirst').addClass("hover");
}, function(e) {
  $('.jQuery-thirst').removeClass("hover");
})

hover(jsFirst, jsThirst);
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {box-sizing: border-box;}

body, p, figure, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {margin: 0;}
ul, ol, dl, li, menu{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.container {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  
}

.native-js {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.title {
  padding: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 18px;
}

.elem {
  padding: 20px;
 background: #411;
  color: #fff;
}

.elem:not(:last-child) {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.hover {
  background: #241;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="native-js container">
 <span class="title">JS</span>
 <div class="js-first elem">Наведи на меня</div>
 <div class="js-second elem">2</div>
 <div class="js-thirst elem">3</div>
</div>

<div class="jQuery container">
 <span class="title">jQuery</span>
 <div class="jQuery-first elem">Наведи на меня</div>
 <div class="jQuery-second elem">2</div>
 <div class="jQuery-thirst elem">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Стоит упомянуть вариант с :target, но это конечно по обстоятельствам... (зато без js)

```
    <div class="test1" id="test1-id"></div>
    <div class="test2" id="test2-id"></div>
    <div class="test3" id="test3-id"></div>
    <a href="#test1-id">link-test-1</a>
    <a href="#test2-id">link-test-2</a>
    <a href="#test3-id">link-test-3</a>
```

```
body {
  font-family: system-ui;
  background: #f06d06;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.test1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.test2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.test3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}

a {
  width 80px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.test1:target {
  background-color: white;
}

.test2:target {
  background-color: blue;
}

.test3:target {
  background-color: black;
}
```